# Error using Scanner.nextLine(): Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Doing some homework here (second assignment, still extremely green...). The object is to read in number `x` and `y` and provide the number in the hundreds position.

For this, I need to use int's I'd assume, as a requirement is to utilize value-returning methods.

I'm just starting to code this, however I'm hitting compile errors already:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:
>       Illegal modifier for parameter anum; only final is permitted
>       Illegal modifier for parameter bnum; only final is permitted
>       Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int at Hundreds.main(Hundreds.java:6)

Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code so far:

```
 import java.util.Scanner; 
 public class Hundreds {
 public static void main (String [] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        private int anum,bnum;
        System.out.println("Hello, for this assignment we are going to require the user to enter two distinct numbers of their choosing");
        System.out.println("Please ensure the numbers are between 100 and 9999");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Please enter your first Number: ");
        anum = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: You don't declare local variables like that in Java. It's telling you that. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: @Numpty: It's good practice to tag homework questions with the tag homework (somebody probably downvoted you because you didn't do that.)

Comment: @Stefan - the homework tag is now deprecated. (Don't ask me to explain!)

Comment: @EdStaub Thanks for the heads up re homework tag!

Comment: This code does not compile, and you don't get that exception from `nextLine()`. Clearly you are *actually* calling `nextInt()`, when the next input isn't a number. In fact it's impossible to see how you ever got that exception when the code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since those variables are local, you can't set visibility scopes to them like private, public, protected.

Move them out of the main function if you intend their scope to be larger.

Answer (score 2):

anum = Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine());

Answer (score 1):

You can also test to see if the next element is an int, and then give feedback to the user if it's not:

```
if(input.hasNextInt()) {
    anum = input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make anum string instead of int. nextLine return a string. don't use private either while defining your string within main.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

`anum = input.nextInt();`

This will still error out if you input a non-integer (try it to see the fun stack trace), but will get you past where you're at currently.

Answer (score 0):

(i) Remove invalid modifiers.
    (ii)Convert string to integer. So make use of `anum=input.nextInt()` instead of anum=input.nextLine()